# Как работать с javascript с другим(внешним) сайтом?

Tags: html, javascript

Вопрос такой.

Как подключить `javascript` со внешнего ресурса?

Или, если точнее, нужно при помощи `javascript` (например `ajax`) отправить и получить данные с другого сайта.

**PS:** проблема возникает со встроенной защитой браузеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить можно через JSONP, а отправить AJAX напрямую не получиться, если только на внешнем ресурсе не поддерживается [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Еще как вариант можно на клиенте (на своём ресурсе) сделать что-то вроде proxy, через который принимать/отправлять запросы на внешний ресурс, на мой взгляд самый стабильный вариант.

Comment: спасибо за хороший ответ. я примерно так и думал.
не хотелось напрягать исходный ресурс, который изначально и так сильно загружен. поэтому хотелось сделать запросы от пользователя напрямую на другой сервер.